# Collecting Longitude and Latitude coordinates of a path from google map into a file

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a good way to download the coordinates of a path or route on google map into a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the street coordinates, directions service is what you may need.

[See directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests)

You can pass the address or location as origin and destination to `directionsService.route()` and use `travelMode DRIVING` . You get the street- [EXAMPLE](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

You can view and store the received coordinates using the chrome console- network tab(you will find downloaded js files with the coordiantes).

---

Another easy and faster way that I like is using the Google Earth software.

Click on the get directions button, enter the start and end locations and enter. Once the route is shown, you can find the `copy the current search results to the clipboard as KML` icon. Open a text file and paste. You can find all the lat lng values there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are helpful and unlike those who voted down for my question. I think they dont understand that the meaning of having stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried the second method. By the way, is there a way to adjust the resolution of the coordinates? which means collect more coordinates from the same path?

Comment: Probably no. Those values downloaded from the server for that route would be fixed